# Deep JSON result in AngularJS partial

Tags: angularjs

I have a 'deep' json result which I have to display in an AngularJS partial.

I want to display some attributes of the 'person' node. I have a single result, with only one person.
Actually, this is what I'm doing :

```
Name : {{country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person.name}}
FirstName : {{country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person.firstName}}
dob : {{country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person.dob}}
Phone : {{country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person.Phone}}
```

What I would like to do is :

```
var person = country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person

Name : {{person.name}}
FirstName : {{person.firstName}}
dob : {{person.dob}}
Phone : {{person.Phone}}
```

Because a partial is a html file with some ng* elements, and I don't want to hack JS within this file, how could I 'create' a local variable ?

Comment: Why can't you do what you've shown here in the controller for the partial where you want to render this.  Instead of just using a local var person, place it on the $scope so `$scope.person = country...`

Comment: Well I can't because it is a 'future', the remote call hasn't been triggered yet. I tried and got a 'lazy' exception

Comment: I edited my answer to add working with promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like NuclearGhost says, probably better to do in the controller if you have that option.

If it's a promise, then, in the controller, you can do this:

```
$scope.country.then(function(country) {
    $scope.person = country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person;
});
```

If you can't do it in the controller, maybe this:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in [country.state.town.city.street.houseNumber.person]">
  Name : {{person.name}}
  FirstName : {{person.firstName}}
  dob : {{person.dob}}
  Phone : {{person.Phone}}
</div>
```

Comment: OK, understood. I'm using a $resource so I need to adapt a bit to work with promise or $http instead of $resource